# Returning top value from a CALL to db.index.fulltext.queryNodes in a subquery

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am loading a CSV and I want to link two nodes, one being the best match of the field of the csv, the other being a different node. How do I limit the CALL to give me the top result and link it to another node

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///mycsv.csv' AS line
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('name', line[1]) yield node, score
# match another node against line[0] then build connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet shows how to use [ORDER BY](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/order-by/) and the aggregating function [COLLECT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to get the highest-scoring node for each line:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///mycsv.csv' AS line
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('name', line[1]) YIELD node, score
WITH line, node
ORDER BY score DESC
WITH line, COLLECT(node)[0] AS n
// match another node against line[0], then connect it to n
```